# Show average of dygraph points, which dynamically amends as the user zooms

Tags: javascript, average, dygraphs

I have seen this - [Horizontal line to show average in dygraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776940/horizontal-line-to-show-average-in-dygraph) - and it doesn't quite answer my question.

I have the following simple dygraph:

```
g2 = new Dygraph(
  document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
  "../newDataFile.csv",
  { ... }
);
```

where newDataFile.csv has two columns.

What I would like to show is the average of the points plotted (as a line or just a number), and for this average to change as I zoom in to different parts of the graph.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var idx=1; //change this value if you have several plots.
var data = g2.rawData_;
var sum = data.map(function(e){return e[idx]})
              .reduce(function(a,b){return a+b});
var average = sum/data.length;
```

If you want to keep only values displayed if the graph is zoomed :

```
var idx=1; //change this value if you have several plots.
var data = g2.rawData_.slice(g2.boundaryIds_[idx][0],g2.boundaryIds_[idx][1]+1);
var sum = data.map(function(e){return e[idx]})
              .reduce(function(a,b){return a+b});
var average = sum/data.length;
```

Comment: If you prefer to use public APIs, you can get the x-axis range via [`xAxisRange`](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#xAxisRange) and data values via [`getValue`](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#getValue).