# dygraph: show maximum and minimum

Tags: dygraphs

My question is similar to [Horizontal line to show average in dygraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776940/horizontal-line-to-show-average-in-dygraph), but not the same. I understand using `underlayCallback` but how do I get the underlying data to calculate maximum and minimum of the data. I was to highlight these point in the data, which is being read from a csv file like so: `gplot.updateOptions({'file': filename});` and I do not know the filename in advance, so have to calculate the max,min on the fly. I feel it is somehow related to `gplot.rawData_` but cannot figure out how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query a Dygraph's data set to get the min and max using its [`getValue` method](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#getValue), like so:

```js
// Calculate the min/max y value in the Dygraph's data set.
function calcMinMax(g) {
  var ymin = g.getValue(0, 1), ymax = g.getValue(0, 1), v;
  for (var i = 0; i < g.numRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < g.numColumns(); j++) {
      y = g.getValue(i, j);
      if (y < ymin) {
        ymin = y;
      } else if (y > ymax) {
        ymax = y;
      }
    }
  }
  return [ymin, ymax];
}
```

To draw the lines, you'll need to use an `underlayCallback`, e.g.

```js
underlayCallback: function(ctx, area) {
  var mm = calcMinMax(this),
      ymin = mm[0],
      ymax = mm[1],
      canvasYmin = this.toDomYCoord(ymin),
      canvasYmax = this.toDomYCoord(ymax);
  ctx.strokeStyle= 'red';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(area.x, canvasYmin);
  ctx.lineTo(area.x + area.w, canvasYmin);
  ctx.moveTo(area.x, canvasYmax);
  ctx.lineTo(area.x + area.w, canvasYmax);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();       
}
```

See [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qigoxegiji/1/edit?js,output) for a working example.

Comment: Any clue what if data zoomed? How to limit xAxis search range?